# Laravel get best comments based on likes and date

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm trying to find a fast way to get comments based on the amount of likes/dislikes and the post date of the comment.

In my commentController I have a `getPopular()` function like this:

```
public function getPopular() 
{ 
    $comments = Comment::all();
    $currenttime = time();

    foreach ($comments as $comment){

        //$date = $currenttime-strtotime($comment->created_at);
        $date = strtotime($comment->created_at);
        $likes = $comment->likes->where('liked', 1)->count();
        $disLikes = $comment->likes->where('liked', 0)->count();
        $likescore = $likes - $disLikes;
        $score= $likescore*$date;

        echo gettype($score)."</br>";
        echo $likescore."</br>";
        echo $date."</br>";
        echo $score."</br></br>";
    }
}
```

With this function im getting a `score` for each comment to sort them. But still this is mainly like based because of the small difference between the time values.

I'm wondering if someone has an idea how to make it so older comments get like a weight what pulls them down. This way you just get the most popular comments at the moment.

Also I was wondering if its possible to make a small selection of potential comments which can end up in the popular section. At the moment I'm just requesting all of them from my database.

Comment: I think, about the time thing you can use days and months instead of the time, something like if one day is past, then you'd lower its' score by half or something like that. But instead of subtracting dislikes from likes to calculate the score, I'd recommend you to read about [Wilson Score](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html).